# How do I search for multiple terms in ResophNotes?

Tags: search

How can I search for two or three words in resophnotes, such as "Perfect Blue"?

I've tried putting them in quotes google style, I tried AND, and &&, but it keeps finding all the irrelevant files with only "Blue" in the title or text.

Comment: Did you try emailing the developer to see if such a feature is even supported?

Comment: Yep. Some changelog implies that AND can be used, but the last update was quite a while back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just playing with this and tooltip is certainly misleading at first read.

There is a widget at the end of the search . . . if clicked one way, term are "and", if clicked the other way terms are "or".

The tooltip only tells you which is currently selected and how to select the other if you want it instead.

Click the button and then type "perfect blue"

Comment: Thanks sir. That answers the question! Except inside my text disk-file-catalogs, it is still highlighting just "blue" instead of auto scrolling to "perfect blue". I guess I need to stop storing files with spaces in their names.